# php do while and then do something else?

Tags: php, do-while

Not sure why this is giving me hell - but I am sure it is an easy fix, that I'm just not seeing.. ?

My query that shows 7 event logos that are upcoming..

[LOGO] [LOGO] [LOGO] [LOGO] [LOGO] [LOGO] [LOGO]

```
$query_Recordset3 = "SELECT id, event_type, event_type_2, event_name,
event_logo,event_date  FROM event_calendar WHERE review_live = 1 AND
event_logo > '0' AND event_date >= CURDATE() ORDER BY event_date ASC
LIMIT 7";
```

My little problem: If I have event without a logo.. so it shows just one or a couple instead of 7.

How it is now if there is two events with logos:

[LOGO] [LOGO] [x] [x] [x] [x] [x]

I am trying to come up with a way to show a default  for the rest of my "logo images"

How I want it to look

[LOGO] [LOGO] [default] [default] [default] [default] [default]

Is my query not right or do I just need to do a fancy "do while" ??

Thanks my NINJAS!! Sorry if there is other do while and query questions.. i just didn't find exactly what i was looking for :-)

Comment: Well, you are looking for `event_logo > '0'`, witch mean, you will always have a result there. How are you planning on determining, witch one is not real?

Comment: Good point, i was thinking about that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just count the number of rows you got and then fill up until you have 7 logos

```
<?php
$query_Recordset3 = "SELECT id, event_type, event_type_2, event_name,
event_logo,event_date  FROM event_calendar WHERE review_live = 1 AND
event_logo > '0' AND event_date >= CURDATE() ORDER BY event_date ASC
LIMIT 7";

$result = $mysqli->query($query_Recordset3) or die(mysqli_error());
for ($i = 0; $row = $result->fetch_row(); $i++) {
    // process row, show logo
}

for (; $i < 7; $i++) {
    // show default
}
```

Comment: Excellent! I will try right away, these both look promising!!

Comment: Got it finally!! This worked well -- thanks!! Now I know the process of a "for" loop!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
$logocount = 7;
while(/*fetch mysql result here*/) {
    //output a logo
    $logocount--;
}
echo str_repeat("Default logo here",$logocount);
```

Comment: Alternatively, have a default value for the `event_logo` column and make the default value point to your default image ;-)